# How to generate access token in spring-authorization-server?

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0

I want add self grant type in spring-authorization-server now days, but I found most solution is unser spring security, so sad about it, and other direction is generate access token directly in my self auth flow.
If you know how to customize grant type or genrate acess token directly, let me know, thanks a lot

Generate access token directly or the method of add grant type in spring-authorization-server